# how to start/stop/restart processes

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, terminal, activity-monitor

As a new comer from Windows OS, I wonder how to start/stop/restart a service on Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8 ?(it's straight forward on Windows using its Task Manager).
I tried Activity Monitor, but it only kills processes, it does not start them.
I tried the command: `launchctl stop *servicename*`  and then the command `launchctl start *servicename*` after I hit return on keyboard after each command the terminal does not show any message so it must be successfull, but when I check out the result in Activity Monitor, it sounds that this command is useless because it has no effect on that process in Activity Monitor.

p.s. I'm sure I typed the right name of the process, I grabbed the name from the list using the command : `launchctl list`

**EDIT: (ps auxwww command output lines)**

`line1:`

```
zend 204 0.0 0.1 602396 2684 ?? Ss 10:53AM 0:00.72 /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/sbin/lighttpd -m /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/lib -f /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/etc/lighttpd.conf -D
```

`line2:`

```
root 202 0.0 0.0 623124 756 ?? Ss 10:53AM 0:00.00 /usr/local/zend/bin/watchdog -c /usr/local/zend/etc/watchdog-lighttpd.ini -u zend -g zend -s lighttpd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is strange to see the questions between "windows migrated" and "default mac" users. :) Windows migrated users usually want "somewhat tweak" the system. Default Mac users - simply "using it".

I'm using MAC much years, and **never** needed to use the launchctl command. If mean never, mean in normal usage, of course sometimes needed use it when installing somethings from the macports - for onetime load of startup files or so.

I'm wondering, why you need start/stop/restart services with launchctl? Asking because if you not an experienced OS X users you probably will screw the system "harmony" :). So, in this case - IMHO - better to ask the specific problem, so ask how to start/stop the specific service.

---

As the answer - check first System preferences. Most common services are in the "Sharing" pane" - like web-server, sshd, CD sharing and so on...

Some third party dmg files with GNU stuff comes with own preference pane too. For example, you can install precompiled MYSQL server with a preference pane, what allow you start-restart the server.

If you don't find the wanted service in prefs, be more precise. What service you need start/stop? The "launchctl" command works as needed to work, ActivityMonitor too. You ofc can use "ps axuwww" or "top" commands from the Terminal too.

Remember, your now in the UNIX world, so nearly anything can be done from the command-line, but usually thats mean really much learning.. ;)

---

EDIT:

try:

```
sudo kill -1 204
              ^-process number
```

from the terminal, or simply kill the daemon from the ActivityMonitor. The watchdog should restart it.

Have you any lighthttpd file in the /Library/LaunchDaemons/*? So, any output form the command:

```
ls /Library/LaunchDaemons | grep -i light
```

if yes, you can use the:

```
sudo launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/filename.plist
sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/filename.plist
```

command for stop/start.

Comment: I liked your quote about Mac vs. Windows migrated users :)& thank you so much for your thorough explanation, however, I've added a PHP extension called: "mysqli.so" to the ini file, and for this to take effect, the service named "lighttpd" must be restarted, and there is no visual interface to do that by a simple click, so I opened terminal and tried the command launcctl but as I told it has no effect on the service, I've tried your command "ps auxwww", it lists complete info about running processes, I've grabbed two lines from this command output that concerns ... to be continued next comment

Comment: that concerns my process "lighttpd":
line1:
zend       204   0.0  0.1   602396   2684   ??  Ss   10:53AM   0:00.72 /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/sbin/lighttpd -m /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/lib -f /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/etc/lighttpd.conf -D

line2:
root       202   0.0  0.0   623124    756   ??  Ss   10:53AM   0:00.00 /usr/local/zend/bin/watchdog -c /usr/local/zend/etc/watchdog-lighttpd.ini -u zend -g zend -s lighttpd

believe it or not, I restarted my machine to get this service restarted !! how can I restart it from terminal or from anywhere else ?
p.s.: it does not exist in SHARING.

Comment: uh, can you edit your question to insert an more readable lines? Will try figure them out anyway, but should help a bit. :)

Comment: I'm sorry for misspelling the name: I meant "process" not "service" .. forgive me ... edited the main subject

Comment: " 
uh, can you edit your question to insert an more readable lines? Will try figure them out anyway, but should help a bit. :) "  .. DONE.

Comment: i've tried your solution on the EDIT seciton above: sudo kill did not kill the process (although the terminal did not give a message so it must be successful), and this drives me crazy, so I simply launched Activity Monitor and killed the process successfully from there. and there is no output from the second command ! p.s. I opened LaunchDaemons folder with Finder, I found that it's empty

Comment: kill -1 send the SIGHUP message to the process. The process simple got the SIGHUP message. The SIGHUP should instruct the lightppd deamon to re-read the config file. If you want really kill the process need to use "kill PID" (or kill -15 PID) or "kill -9 PID". (man kill - manual for the kill command)

Comment: so how can I start the process after I kill it ?

Comment: The watchdog should restart it. if not /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/sbin/lighttpd -m /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/lib -f /usr/local/zend/gui/lighttpd/etc/lighttpd.conf -D command (as you see it in the process list). I don't know your lighttpd installation. Mine installation HAS LaunchDaemon startup file.

Comment: the watchdog did not restart it, but I could restart it using the command in the process list, this is really nice :) thank you so much for your kind help. I'm sorry can't vote up because it needs 15+ reputation .. but I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

> I'm using MAC much years, and never needed to use the launchctl command. If mean never, mean in normal usage, of course sometimes needed use it when installing somethings from the macports - for onetime load of startup files or so.
>
> I'm wondering, why you need start/stop/restart services with launchctl? Asking because if you not an experienced OS X users you probably will screw the system "harmony" :). So, in this case - IMHO - better to ask the specific problem, so ask how to start/stop the specific service.

I don't see a problem with asking the wider question as to how services are started and stopped if it enables the OP to better understand the underlying mechanics of the system.

As to why you would want to do this, one good reason would be to remotely kill errant processes on remote machines via Apple Remote Desktop. I do this frequently for our network users at school and it can save a lot of leg work (as well as avoiding entering repetitive terminal commands).

ARD users will want to kill processes by name rather than by PID as the process ID isn't necessarily the same each time the process is initiated...

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```

...would be a useful command for ARD users as it's repeatable regardless of PID, whereas...

```
sudo kill -1 211
```

...would very likely only work to kill **coreaudiod** on the occasion that its PID was actually **211**, and definitely wouldn't be an ARD command worth saving for future use. This may seem obvious to "advanced" users but unfamiliar users may not realise the difference.

Comment: Thought this was very helpful! Yes, I just wanted to restart the SystemUIServer which manages the menu bar, essentially refreshing it to look at some plists I just updated. Not having to look for the process ID saved me a lot of time. Thanks!